# Flow of the vector field with surface integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, surfaces

We are asked to calculate with the help of a suitable surface integral, the flow of the vector field F=(z,y,x) through the sphere with center (0,0,0) and radius 1, from the center of the sphere and outwards.

I am really aware what exactly to do to solve it, but should I implement Stokes theorem, or it can be solved only through parametrization?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why should you not apply divergence theorem? Yes you should and that gives you a ready answer, without any integration. Unless the exercise requires you to do surface integral.

Comment: If the problem wants you to find the outward flux of $\vec{F}$ through a sphere of radius $1$ centered around the origin $(0,0,0)$ "with the help of a suitable surface integral," you're required to evaluate $\iint_{S}\big(\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}\big)\mathrm{d}S$ directly.

Comment: If nothing, divergence theorem tells you what answer you should get.

Comment: If it matters, it's possible (and easy once you've seen an example) to write the outward unit normal field for the unit sphere in terms of Cartesian coordinates, then to compute the dot product with $F$ as a function of $x$, $y$, $z$, and finally to evaluate the integral by symmetry and geometry (without really doing calculus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the outward unit normal field on the unit sphere $S$ is $n = (x, y, z)$, so $F \cdot n = 2xz + y^2$. We need to integrate this function over $S$, a task that can be done by symmetry and geometry:

- The integral over $S$ of a function that is odd in any variable is $0$.
- By symmetry,
  $$
  \iint_{S} y^{2}\, dS = \iint_{S} x^{2}\, dS = \iint_{S} z^{2}\, dS.
  $$
  But on the unit sphere,
  $$
  \iint_{S} (x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2})\, dS = \iint_{S} 1\, dS,
  $$
  which is the area of $S$.